# Copy shared objects to jniLibs when using cmake for Android

Tags: android, c++, gradle, cmake

I have recently started to move my Android build from Ant to Gradle and then I want to use cmake for my C++ code. The build is currently running fine, but no shared objects are copied to the jniLibs folder where they need to be before creating the aar file (this is a library project, currently building on Windows 10).

I have looked at the tasks being run when building with `./gradlew assembleDebug`. They are:

```
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preReleaseUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72221Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42221Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileLint UP-TO-DATE
:app:copyDebugLint UP-TO-DATE
:app:copyLibs
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:incrementalDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:app:extractDebugAnnotations UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:app:packageDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateJsonModelDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:externalNativeBuildDebug
  building E:\path\to\app\Android\app\.externalNativeBuild\cmake\debug\libs\x86\libApp.so
  building 
:app:mergeDebugJniLibFolders
:app:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug
:app:transformNative_libsWithSyncJniLibsForDebug
:app:bundleDebug
:app:compileDebugSources
:app:assembleDebug
```

This is all well and good, but the folder `app/src/main/jniLibs` is empty, thus no shared objects are copied to the aar file. So then there's the question of how to add a gradle build step to actually copy these files. This has proven to be very difficult to do.

**Approach 1:**

Try to create a copy task to run before the `:app:bundleDebug` task. I have made a few attempts to do this:

First possibility:

```
task copyLibs(type: Copy, dependsOn: 'bundleDebug') {
    from ('.externalNativeBuild/cmake/debug/libs') {
        include '**/libApp.so'
    }
    into 'src/main/jniLibs'
}
```

Second possibility:

```
task copyLibs(type: Copy) {
    from ('.externalNativeBuild/cmake/debug/libs') {
        include '**/libApp.so'
    }
    into 'src/main/jniLibs'
}

tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
    if (task.name ==  'bundleDebug') {
        task.dependsOn copyLibs
    }
}
```

Note that the paths are correct, because I can force the copy to be done by having `task copyLibs <<` with a copy step inside instead. This will then be copied on the *second* run of the build since the shared objects do not exist on the first. (Since the task is run at the beginning.)

**Approach 2:**

Do the copy in cmake. This is feasible, but not desirable. Hence I have not gone down this route.

**Here is my build.gradle:**

Comments and more info is as comments in the below.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

// This task is run before everything else, so it does the copy on the *second* build,
// thereby copying the shared objects from the *previous* build.
//task copyLibs << {
//    copy {
//        from ('.externalNativeBuild/cmake/debug/libs') {
//            include '**/libApp.so'
//        }
//        from ('.externalNativeBuild/cmake/release/libs') {
//            include '**/libApp.so'
//        }
//        into 'src/main/jniLibs'
//        includeEmptyDirs = false
//    }
//}

// This is the task signature if tasks.whenTaskAdded below is *not* used. If both are
// used we get a circular dependency.
//task copyLibs(type: Copy, dependsOn: 'bundleDebug') {

task copyLibs(type: Copy) {
    from ('.externalNativeBuild/cmake/debug/libs') {
        include '**/libApp.so'
    }
    into 'src/main/jniLibs'
}

tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
    if (task.name ==  'bundleDebug') {}
        // This dependecy *is* set. This can be seen by using task copyLibs(type: Copy, dependsOn: 'bundleDebug')
        // together with this and get a circular dependency.
        task.dependsOn copyLibs
    }
}

// Prints:
// [task ':app:assemble', task ':app:assembleAndroidTest', task ':app:assembleDefault', task ':app:buildDependents',
// task ':app:buildNeeded', task ':app:check', task ':app:compileLint', task ':app:connectedCheck', task ':app:copyLibs',
// task ':app:deviceCheck', task ':app:extractProguardFiles', task ':app:lint', task ':app:preBuild', task ':app:sourceSets',
// task ':app:uninstallAll']
println(tasks)

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
//    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.2" // Tried using latest for good measures

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 12
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        // Some defines to build certain architectures, e.g. with './gradlew -Ponly-x86 assembleDebug'. This is working.
        if (project.hasProperty('only-x86')) {
            ndkConfig.abiFilters = ["x86"] as Set<String>
        }
        else if (project.hasProperty('only-armeabi-v7a')) {
            ndkConfig.abiFilters = ["armeabi-v7a"] as Set<String>
        }
        else {
            ndkConfig.abiFilters = ["x86", "armeabi-v7a"] as Set<String>
        }

        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags    "-fexceptions", "-frtti", "-Wno-error"
                arguments   "-DANDROID_STL=gnustl_static"
            }
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
        }
        debug {
        }
    }

    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path '../../../CMakeLists.txt'
        }
        beforeEvaluate( println("I ma printed at the top.") )
        afterEvaluate { println("I am printed before compiling.") }
    }
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete "${rootProject.buildDir}"
    delete "${project.buildDir}"
    delete "${project.projectDir}/.externalNativeBuild"
    delete fileTree(dir: "${project.projectDir}/src/main/jniLibs", include: '**/*.so')
}
```

**Other info:**

- cmake version: 3.6.3155560
- The aar file is properly created if the shared objects are in the jniLibs folder, so the build is actually working except for the copy step.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured out how to do it in the end. To include built shared objects from some place we need to use `sourceSets.main.jniLibs.srcDirs` inside the `android` part of our build.gradle. The example below fetches is directly from the Android cmake output directory for shared objects (for debug).

For example:

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        ...
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
        }
        debug {
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            // Bundle so files with the final apk.
            // NOTE: Currently bundles all shared objects in that directory.
            // It was not straightforward to exclude in Android sourceSets at the time of writing,
            // see https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=64957
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['.externalNativeBuild/cmake/debug/libs']
        }
    }

    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path '../../../CMakeLists.txt'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea. The '.externalNativeBuild/cmake/debug/libs' folder is a build foler, and where to locate other prebuild share library file sooner.

I think the best idea is copy your dependencies library file to a jniLib  foler which under version controller.

If use android gradle plugin newer 4.0.0, the plugin will do the copy job automatically(see [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/gradle-external-native-builds#jniLibs)).

Comment: This question is probably outdated with the latest Android toolchain. Feel free to post an updated answer to help out those who use the latest tools.