# ANDROID NDK Compilation CMAKE

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, cmake, java-native-interface

I have an Android Project with 2 modules "A" and  "B". I am using NDK i.e., CPP code in the project. So i added all my CPP code to Module B. I create a CMakeList.txt file in Module B and configured it in gradle file. I added Module A and Module B to the "Settings.gradle". I observe that though code is being compiled but my .so file is not reflecting in the APK. Is there any additional steps i have to take so that Output of Module B is being copied to Module A.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with a prebuilt .so, and this approach is the one I settled on: [Copy shared objects to jniLibs when using cmake for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39613452/copy-shared-objects-to-jnilibs-when-using-cmake-for-android)

There's another way to do it using a copy script with cmake, but you basically copy to the jnilibs directory of your project source.