# Android Studio: Run a gradle task after compiling java but before NDK build

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin

I have an Android project that needs to do code generation after the Java is built but before the NDK compiles the C++. Normally this is all contained within the build task. I've found it's possible to hook into tasks that are created dynamically by the android plugin.

```
afterEvaluate {
    // ...
    generateJsonModel(BUILDVARIANT).dependsOn 'myCodeGenTask'
    externalNativeBuild(BUILDVARIANT).dependsOn 'myCodeGenTask'

    myCodeGenTask.mustRunAfter 'compileRetrolambda(BUILDVARIANT)'
    // (You won't have this if you're not using retrolambda -
    // It just happens to run at the end of the java build)
}
```

This worked fine for a while but after recent plugin updates these tasks are not always present. I am getting errors that the properties do not exist.

Is there a more reliable way to insert a task in the middle?

Comment: Link it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39613452/copy-shared-objects-to-jnilibs-when-using-cmake-for-android

Comment: Thanks for the tip but I don't think I can apply it here. They had a similar problem (how do I hook into the android tasks?), but they were able to solve it neatly by instead adjusting the sourceSets. I am hoping for something similarly neat, but it won't work for my problem.

Comment: Just created ticket for bug which is similar to yours, you can track it, maybe Google guys will fix it someday: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/issues/450